# sed, awk or similar - delete whole line and 2 lines above if pattern matches followed by a blank line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Sample text:

```
heading1
heading2
data
data
data

heading1
heading2

heading1
heading2
data
data
data
```

I want to delete the section in the middle that doesn't have any data. That is; if heading2 is followed by a blank line, delete heading2, heading1 and the blank line above.

I've found how to remove lines only when followed by a blank line, and how to delete n lines above/below a pattern, but can't work out how to merge the two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS="\n"} NF>2' input.file
```

While `awk` by default operates on a per line basis, *records* doesn't necessarily need to be a single line. Using `RS` (the *input record separator*) you can define how *records* are separated.

I'm setting `RS` in the `BEGIN` block to a blank line to separate records by paragraphs and `FS` to newline to separate fields by a newline.

`NF` holds is the number of fields in the current record. `NF>2` checks for any record that contains more than 2 lines - and if this condition is met, `awk` prints the record.

`ORS` is the *output record separator*. I'm setting it to a blank line, as `FS`, in order to separate individual records in output.

Comment: OK, that seems to work. Thanks. I will test it more thoroughly on Monday (it's home time, and this is work related). Can you explain what each part does please?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Trying to get an idea now, `++` for innovation!

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your edit. While it didn't matter in this case, I wasn't aware of the fact that the default FS is still in effect *in addition* to newline when `RS=''`. (Even if the manual clearly states that! :) ). I was already thinking that it probably would have been better to use `BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS="\n"}` instead of some *hidden* magic that needs explanation.

Comment: PS: Just realizing that it actually *does* matter because *real world* data would unlikely look like `heading1`. Let me change that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar approach that will eliminate printing the last empty line:

```
awk -v RS= 'NF>2{print sep $0; sep=ORS}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/^$/M!ba;s/\n/&/3;t;d' file
```

Store records delimited by an empty line, in the pattern space. If a record contains 3 or more newlines print it otherwise delete it.